# Open a deeplink while the app is already open

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am having an issue with a deeplink. If I have the app open and I repeatedly try to deeplink I can end up in a situation where the activity that should be accept the deeplink does not get started but instead the task is brought to the front. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the launchMode of your activity (android:launchMode="singleInstance") in your AndroidManifest file :

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```